# Two stack navigator in react native

Tags: navigation-drawer, react-native

I have below codebase for navigation

```
// drawer stack
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
  screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
  screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
})

const DrawerNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerStack }
}, {
  headerMode: 'float',
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'green'},
    title: 'Logged In to your app!',
    headerLeft: <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>Menu</Text>
  })
})

// login stack
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
  signupScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  loginScreen: { screen: Login },
//   forgottenPasswordScreen: { screen: ForgottenPasswordScreen, navigationOptions: { title: 'Forgot Password' } }
}, {
  headerMode: 'float',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'red'},
    title: 'You are not logged in'
  }
})

// Manifest of possible screens
const Nav = createStackNavigator({
  loginStack: { screen: LoginStack },
  drawerStack: { screen: DrawerNavigation }
}, {
  // Default config for all screens
  headerMode: 'none',
  title: 'Main',
  initialRouteName: 'loginStack'
})
```

One is for without login and other is for after login

Initially it is going to login/signup page correctly

Then after login I have just doing this

this.props.navigation.navigate("screen3");

But the drawer is not showing.

How to render drawer after use login.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try switchNavigator?

```
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

.
.
.
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    LoginStack: LoginStack,
    DrawerStack: DrawerNavigation
  },
  { headerMode: "none", initialRouteName: "LoginStack" }
);

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default App;
```

When you want to switch to next stack use the following,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerStack");
```

And if you want to open the drawer use the following on button click,

```
import { DrawerActions } from "react-navigation";
...
...
...
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
```

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerStack");... but how to redirect to any screen

Comment: First you have to set any screen for default,
eg: initialRouteName: "Screen1",
And for switching between screens you can use,

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: "Screen2,
      params: { }
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);

Don't forgot to import,
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from "react-navigation";

Comment: I am learning react-native, so is there any sample for this, that I could download and run

Comment: You can try with this, 
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/NavigationPlayground